# Label toolbar not showing up even though it is checked in toolbar menu

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, toolbar

I have recently discovered that even though I chose to display the label toolbar through the toolbar menu that it is nowhere to be seen on the monitor. Has anyone encountered this or know a fix to it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, what version of desktop are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I've asked some question in a comment above but what you can try right away is resetting the ArcMap template:

Close all instances of arc map

Locate and rename the Normal.mxt in ESRI\DesktopXX.X\ArcMap\Templates\Normal.mxt

start ArcMap and turn on the labelling toolbar.

Comment: I've discovered that it was an issue with multiple monitors- laptop lid closed.... when I opened it up it popped up on one of the screens at which point I locked it onto the menu bar to stop it from floating.  Thank you for the quick turn around on the comments and suggested assistance.

Comment: Apparently my initial comment was removed. PErhaps i didn't add it before closing my browser - I was indeed asking if you use multiple monitors.  In any case, you can answer and accept your own question - this is perfectly acceptable and encouraged here.